# What are the steps to create a custom widget based on taxonomy_select?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to create a widget for fields of type "taxonomy_term_reference". The widget "taxonomy_select" is very nearly what I need to build, but needs some modification. I have seen examples that start with a given widget to build a custom version. The function below fails because there is no "taxonomy_select_field_widget_form" defined. Where is the "taxonomy_select" form creation code?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function taxonomy_multiselect_add_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

  $element += taxonomy_select_field_widget_form($form, $form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element);

  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `taxonomy_term_reference` field type uses the core `options_select` widget and implements [`hook_options_list()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!options!options.api.php/function/hook_options_list/7) to provide the values, the taxonomy module doesn't implement any of the widget code itself.

The `options_select` widget is defined in [`options_field_widget_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21options%21options.module/function/options_field_widget_info/7) in the code options.module file (inside the field module folder). The form elements themselves are built up in [`options_field_widget_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!options!options.module/function/options_field_widget_form/7) in the same file. They're pretty well commented so you should be able to get a good idea of how they work.

I'd also recommend the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples/) if you haven't already got it, it has a field type/widget example module with good sample code and comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now trying to customize the core options multiselect with this code:

```
function taxonomy_multiselect_add_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

  $instance['widget']['type'] = 'options_select';
  $element += options_field_widget_form($form, $form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element);

  return $element;
}
```

But my widget now builds a multiple-value table with the default first row being the multiselect. How can I build my own identical version of the multiselect to begin modifying?

Comment: UPDATE: I now have a good starting point for modifying the options_select widget. I needed to supply a 'behaviors' array to my hook_field_widget_info that sets 'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_CUSTOM